# Finding correlations between large numbers of features

Tags: correlation, data-mining, feature-selection, association-rules

I have data which is composed of several thousand continuous features. What sorts of ML or statistical algorithms can efficiently find the rules for which features are most correlated with other features? For example, I could "brute force" the problem by calculating spearman or pearson correlation for every feature to every other feature and choose a correlation cutoff of 0.9, but is there a more efficient algorithm? (with an implementation in R?)

I have looked into association rule learning and the apriori algorithm, but at least the R implementation seems to work with discrete features only. My features are *very* non-discrete, and values range in orders from 0 to 10,000, where abundances definitely do matter, so I don't want to just discretize the data. I think I want something like apriori, only for continuous variables.